# Is there a way to limit a smart playlist by the year field in iTunes 12

Tags: itunes, smart-playlist

I run a rather complicated stack of smart playlists to populate my iPod with music and videos, from the top one that pulls out the files I added to my library first, to the middle range that sorts that playlist by how many times I have listened to the files, to the actually used playlists that sort it out by media type (i.e. TV Show, Audiobook, and music genres)  These low level playlists I have I usually limit to 23 items since this is the most I can have on one screen without scrolling, however I have stumbled across a small problem.  I like to listen to my music by year, the oldest stuff first, but I have no way to LIMIT the playlist by this field.  I can limit by random, but then my audiobooks show up all out of order, same with artist and album, sometimes I'll get the third book in the trilogy before the first one.

Can playlist limit matches by year so I can always get the earliest stuff first?

Comment: Interesting question. Just one thing, besides the reference to iTunes 12 in your title, you haven't specified the exact version of iTunes 12 you're using? There have been quite a number of revisions since the first iTunes 12 was released in October 2014, so this _may_ be relevant. You can use the _edit_ link below your question to edit it.